# XML to Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

What's the easiest way of loading a simple XML file (like the one offered in StackExchange data dumps) into an Excel sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Excel 2007, go **Data->From Other Sources->From XML Data Import**